# jQuery - Small snippet for number formatting not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have the following code for formatting numbers as user types:

```
//Add commas as user types
$('input.num_format').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
});
```

Working JS Fiddle of code above: http://jsfiddle.net/d0u5hu36/

Now after doing the front-end for my site I'm doing the backend with PHP, but when I try to submit the data from the input that has the above JS snippet I just get the first 3 characters from a number for example: from "350,000" I'll just be able to submit to my table "350", why is this happening? I'd like to be able to submit "350000" I believe this has to do with the client side.

Additional information:
The MySQL column is "mediumint(9)"

Answer (score 1):

When submitting the value, try encoding the character "," before submitting, since , has special meaning if you are posting via form, you can use

```
  encodeURIComponent()
```

At the server side using PHP, you may be required to do a additional decode

```
  utf8_decode(string)
```

For example, while performing form submission via GET a ideal url would look like [one control name multiple values] [Comma usage]

```
test.php?parameter=a1,a2,a3
```

Hope it helps!

UPDATE

Try looping the variable[variable for control name where the value is being formatted with comma] in POST/GET in php and concatenate them in a string [assuming you are using POST]

```
 $str = "";
foreach($_POST['<control_name>'] as $item)
{
    $str = $str.$item;
 }
 echo $str;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, but this wasn't exactly the answer for what I asked. You gived me the idea tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hemant for giving me the idea. It's actually a server side issue, since the field is an integer it ignores the numbers after the comma. So what I did was deleting all characters other than numbers with the following regex code:

```
preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',strip_tags($string));
```